# Where does the name for PostgreSQL module `amcheck` come from?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL features a contrib module called [`amcheck`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/amcheck.html). This module provides functions that allow you to verify the logical consistency of the structure of relations. Its functionalities originally appeared in PostgreSQL 10.

Where does the name come from? I understand the `check` part of the name, but what is the meaning of `am`?

Comment: AM = **A**ccess **M**ethod as far as I know. https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“am” stands for *access method*, which is a way to access a table. You can find the same abbreviation in the system catalog `pg_am`, which lists all known access methods.

A historical note: the module was added in v10 with [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=3717dc149ecf44b8be95350a68605ba7299474fd) after [this discussion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAM3SWZQzLMhMwmBqjzK%2BpRKXrNUZ4w90wYMUWfkeV8mZ3Debvw%40mail.gmail.com). Originally it only supported checks in B-tree indexes. Back then, “am” was roughly equivalent to “index type” in PostgreSQL slang, so the module name would have been understood as “index integrity check”. PostgreSQL v12 introduced *table access methods* (other ways to store data in tables), so that the meaning of *access method* has broadened. In v14, amcheck got a new function `verify_heapam` to check the integrity of tables, so the name “amcheck” has stood the test of time.